# Removing consecutive duplicates in a tuple

Tags: python, list, duplicates, zip

I am trying to not print consecutive duplicates with a zip list but I am a little confused about the tuple structure here.  If it were a simple list I would either use groupby or something simple like if y[i] != y[i-1] but this does not work here. I also can't seem to append it to a list which I tried... I am missing something in the details here.

and example input would be:

```
aa b aa aa b c
```

which would give me:

```
aa b aa b c
```

here is my code so far:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys

in_file = sys.argv[1]

with open(in_file) as f:
    do stuff not related to this question...

for x in zip(*lis):
    for y in x :
        if y[i] != y[i-1]:
            print(y+' ', end='')
    print('\n')
```

Sorry if this question is confusing, feel free to make any changes to help others :-)

Comment: You can use `itertools.groupby`.

Comment: Hm... there must be a dupe somewhere...

Comment: What is the input example here? A list or a string?

Comment: @Psidom, it is a string

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, I thought so too but I can not figure it out, like I said I am missing something silly here.

Comment: I guess you can split it by white space and then remove dupes with your method.

Comment: I marked as a dupe because I don't see how the problem solution will be any different than the dupe - being a string or tuple initially won't change much.

Comment: @badner `' '.join(k for k, _ in itertools.groupby('aa b aa aa b c'.split()))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
from itertools import groupby
a = "aa b aa aa b c"
q = tuple(a.split()) #here q is tuple 
''.join([x for x,y in groupby(q)]) # use your tuple inside groupby
```

Comment: You don't need the if condition.

Comment: yes you're correct.. updated thanks

Comment: see that is what I tried but I am still getting a tuple error:

Comment: print(''.join([k for k,y in groupby(x.split())]))
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: i used split because i am having string.. if you want you can use it directly. BTW i will change my answer check it

Comment: ok I will try it

Comment: @MohideenibnMohammed perfect!